# variable is already defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

sometime i need to replace a variable value to another

so i use this method

```
var $$test = "First",
    $$test = "Second";
```

the code work fine but i use jsfiddle JSHint button to check any error on JavaScript (it helped me a lot)

but i got this error '$$test' is already defined

[image]

so what is the ideal method to re define any variable

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're declaring the same variable twice.

```
var a = foo, a = bar;
```

Is the same as:

```
var a = foo;
var a = bar;
```

Just break your code in two lines, and you won't get that warning. Like this:

```
var a = foo;
a = bar;
```

Also notice that if you declare a variable with a value, and then right after that you change its value, the first line is a [noop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).

Comment: @JimmyTodd - your fiddle works for me, no error in the console - or am I just getting confused because the page says "check the console" rather than "Press the JSHint button"? If I do that it _does_ give a JSHint warning because you're still declaring the same variable twice.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a comma. You should redefine it as a new statement:

```
var $$test = 'First';
$$test = 'Second';
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is trying to define two variable s called $$test. They need to have uniuque names.
Try using $$test1 and $$test2

updated for you http://jsfiddle.net/9CdJN/2/

```
(function($){

var $$test = "First";
 $$test = "Second";

console.log($$test);

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I need to redefine the same variable

Comment: @JimmyTodd - You're _not_ trying to "redefine" the same variable, you're trying to change the variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a comma `,` at the end of the first line instead of a semi-colon `;`.

Each Javascript statement ends with a semi-colon. You can define multiple variables with a single `var` by separating them all with a comma.

```
var var1=1, var2=2, var3=3;
```

is the same as

```
var var1=1,
    var2=2,
    var3=3;
```

Because you had a comma in the first line, the browser believes you are declaring two different variables with the same name. To fix it, just change it to this:

```
var $$test = "First";
    $$test = "Second";
```